# Event sourcing with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

What is the best practice to structure a message for a topic containing different types that need to be sorted.

**Example**

Topic: user-events
Event types: UserCreatedEvent, UserUpdatedEvent, UserDeletedEvent.
Those events need to be saved in the same topic and partition to guarantee the order.

**Possible solutions I see**

1. Single schema containing all event type fields
2. Schema containing all event types schemas. `{eventId, timestamp, userCreated: {}, userUpdated: {}, userDeleted: {}}`
3. Different schema for event using `Avro union`

**Pro**

1. Easy to implement and process as a stream
2. Easy to implement, process as a stream and setup required fields for each event type
3. Every message is an event

**Cons**

1. Possible to have many empty fields and it's not possible to specify required fields per event type
2. Not clear the message type without inspecting the payload
3. Difficult to deserialize (GenericRecord)

Are there other possible solutions, how do you normally handle a topic with different message types? How do you process this king of topics?

Any reference to code example is welcome.

**UPDATE**

There are two articles from confluent trying to explain who to solve this:

- [Should You Put Several Event Types in the Same Kafka Topic?](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/?_ga=2.40997922.1475570076.1617864392-1665684.1617701833&_gac=1.18500171.1617702378.CjwKCAjwjbCDBhAwEiwAiudBy-gMRrqUB3h99tBUpzRrRGtefdZfYruCwa-U6IMWH7FjothaoARkIBoCbsQQAvD_BwE)
- [Putting Several Event Types in the Same Topic](https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/?_ga=2.11720756.1475570076.1617864392-1665684.1617701833&_gac=1.191434328.1617702378.CjwKCAjwjbCDBhAwEiwAiudBy-gMRrqUB3h99tBUpzRrRGtefdZfYruCwa-U6IMWH7FjothaoARkIBoCbsQQAvD_BwE)

My opinion on the articles is that they give you only a partial answer.

The first tells you when is a good idea to save different types into the same topic, and event sourcing is a good fit.
The second, it’s more technical and illustrate the possibility of doing this with Avro union.

But none of them explain in details how to do it with a real example.

I have seen projects on github where they simplified the scenario by creating a single schema, more as a state than actual event (point 1.).
Talking to someone with experience using kafka, came up with the solution explained at point 2 by nesting the events into a “carrying event”.

I managed yesterday (I will share the solution asap) to use avro union and deserialize the events as GenericRecord and do transformation based on the event type.
Since I didn’t find any similar solution I was curious to know if I'm missing something, like drawbacks (e.g. Ksqldb doesn’t support different types) or better practices to do the same in kafka.

Comment: Do you need separate schemas? You could define the action as its own field `(id, timestamp, action, user)`. You could also use separate topics, then a processor to combine all events into a unified "users" (compacted) topic where recent events are post-create/update/delete

Comment: If I do separate into different topics, then would I be able to maintain the order of the events while processing? e.g. created-user-events, updated-user-events and deleted-user-events.

Comment: That depends on what's actually maintaining user records. You could simply ignore all deletes and updates by checking what's already been created

Answer (score 0):

In cases when I need to transfer different objects through one topic, I use the transport container. It stores some meta information about nested object, and serialized object, that you want to transport.

Avsc schema of the container can be like

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "TransportContainer",
  "namespace": "org.example",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "event_type", 
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "event_timestamp",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "event",
      "type": "bytes"
    }
  ]
}
```

In "event_type" field you should store the type of the event. You should use it to determine, which schema you need to use to deserialize a nested object, stored in the "event" field. Also, it helps to avoid deserialization of every nested object, if you want to read objects only with a specific type.

Comment: Note: this is very similar to the Cloudevents schema spec

Comment: Cloudevents schema spec seems to me an equivalent of avro schema with schema registry.